# How can I read a specific part of a text file?

Tags: c#, project

In C, I was able to read a specific part of a text file like this:

```c
game_results new_statistic(FILE* input, int* rounds) {
    game_results out;

   char temp[300];
   if(fgets(temp, 300, input) != NULL) {
      if(strlen(temp) < 3) {
         fgets(temp, 300, input);
         ++*rounds;
      }

   /* Sorting the string and giving all the variables to the struct game_results */
   sscanf(temp, "%s %d / %d %s %s - %s %d - %d %lf" , out.weekday, &out.date_day, &out.date_month, out.timet,
   out.hometeam, out.awayteam, &out.home_goal, &out.away_goal, &out.crowd);
   out.rounds = *rounds;
   }
   return out;
}
```

How is it possible to do it like that in C#?

I need specific information that is in the text file. I want to read the value of Amount of Rooms, then the program needs to know that the first roomname is "Stue" and has the value 1 which represents powerconnectors in the room. Next it will read "tv", then 200 which is the powerusage, and 3 for standbyusage. Then it will do the same for the room kitchen.

The text in the file looks the following:

```
Amount of Rooms: 2
Stue, 1
tv, 200, 3
Kitchen, 1
Fridge, 100, 2
```

Comment: I have tried different things. But i can't find a solution that is like the one i did with C. I know C# is a different language but it would be nice if it was possible to do something alike. The C code is in the pastebin.

Comment: What different things have you tried? Show your effort and the point where it is failing. We might be able to help you after that.

Comment: I want to read the value of Amount of Rooms, then the program needs to know that the first roomname is "Stue" and has the value 1 which represents powerconnectors in the room. Next it will read "tv", then 200 which is the powerusage, and 3 for standbyusage.
Then it will do the same for the room kitchen

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) method to open a file and query it for the data you need, and it'll only read enough lines to satisfy your query.

So to get the first line, use LINQ's `First()` method, then split on the colon and grab the number.

```
var rooms = Convert.ToInt32(File.ReadLines(@"c:\yourFile.txt").First().Split(':').Last());
```

To get the rest, you could do it a few different ways. I prefer LINQ, so here's another example.

Read everything *except* the first line (skip it), then split on the comma and create a dictionary.

```
var data = (from f in File.ReadLines(@"c:\yourFile.txt").Skip(1)
            let parts = f.Split(',')
            select new { key = parts[0], value = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]) })
          .ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

if the information is on the same lines each time a simple way to do it would be with the Streamreader

```
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\EXPORT.TXT");
        while (file.Peek() != -1)
        {
            line = file.ReadLine();
            string test1;
            string readdate;
            test1 = line.Substring(0, 8);//1
            FullName = line.Substring(8, 20);//2
            Address = line.Substring(28, 20);//3
            ModuleNumber = line.Substring(48, 10);//4
            test1 = line.Substring(58, 4);//5
            ReadType = line.Substring(62, 1);//6
            Service = line.Substring(63, 1);//7
            test1 = line.Substring(64, 1);//8
            test1 = line.Substring(65, 2);//9
            test1 = line.Substring(67, 9);//10
       }
```

This particular code is what I use to read a fixed width file, but you could add each line to a list, I think it would be better if you text file was in a format of either fixed width or delimited.

EDIT: I would have loved to have been able to suggest this in a comment but since I'm not allowed to comment, I put this as an answer with a little more detail.